# unserialize not returning array

Tags: php, serialization

unserialize function is not returning in array.

this is my serialize data when I echo it.

```
a:31:{s:2:"id";s:2:"71";s:3:"sku";s:6:"cp1038";s:4:"name";s:25:"Dual tone stripped pillow";s:4:"slug";s:29:"dual-tone-stripped-pillow-222";s:8:"route_id";s:3:"152";s:11:"description";s:1259:"

Address Home, a brand new Luxe Lifestyle boutique, Everything from plus bed and table Linen to cushions, curtain and upholstery fabric in silk, cotton, satin, velvet, jacquard and polyester, embellished with foil printing, contemporary embroidery, crystals, quilting and other types of texturing, including tiny metallic pieces. The current range, which shows traces of Moroccan and French textile influences, but is all about very �now� color combinations - whites and whites; chocolate with teal and copper; black with white and silver; fuchsia, orange depth. coordinate easily with elaborate accessories; German hand-blown glass vases, lamps, lights, serving and dining pieces, glassware, flowers and candles. Even some fab spmdly-legged French chairs, handcrafted from acrylic. Call it my nesting instinct or magpie syndrome, but i just can�t re sist seeking out stuff to enhance my bachelorettepad. Whenever there�s a new home decor store on the horizon, I�m usually one of the early check-outers. Recently, my seeker sense was tingling so much I JUST knew there was something really exciting coming up. And how right I was!
";s:7:"excerpt";s:32:"Dual tone stripped pillow 2 exec";s:5:"price";s:7:"1000.00";s:9:"saleprice";s:4:"0.00";s:13:"free_shipping";s:1:"0";s:9:"shippable";s:1:"1";s:7:"taxable";s:1:"1";s:14:"fixed_quantity";s:1:"0";s:6:"weight";s:2:"10";s:11:"track_stock";s:1:"1";s:16:"related_products";s:0:"";s:6:"images";s:460:"{"81503e57d46823464db9e990faa600b0":{"filename":"81503e57d46823464db9e990faa600b0.jpg","alt":"showcase","caption":""},"ba103b97070ede81acab8f593068ece1":{"filename":"ba103b97070ede81acab8f593068ece1.jpg","alt":"","caption":""},"cdd790bd0a17f93af430d663cde823e1":{"filename":"cdd790bd0a17f93af430d663cde823e1.jpg","alt":"","caption":""},"769557dd643978d50d3bd76e5ca3211d":{"filename":"769557dd643978d50d3bd76e5ca3211d.jpg","alt":"","caption":"","primary":true}}";s:9:"seo_title";s:0:"";s:4:"meta";s:0:"";s:7:"enabled";s:1:"1";s:5:"color";s:1:"3";s:4:"size";s:2:"20";s:14:"child_products";s:1:"0";s:15:"mapped_products";s:11:"73,37,36,29";s:10:"hover_name";s:15:"Dual Tone Hover";s:10:"base_price";s:7:"1000.00";s:9:"file_list";a:0:{}s:12:"post_options";s:0:"";s:5:"is_gc";b:0;s:8:"quantity";d:2;s:8:"subtotal";d:2000;}
```

when I unserialize it and var_dump it it gives me boolean(false).I tried to use htmlspecialchars(), trim(),stripslashes() but not working

Please help

Comment: may be its not unserializable..thats why its returning false, do you get notice as well, and can you show how are you serializing your array..?

Comment: @Sudhir wht it can't unserialize I am using $items_desc  = unserialize(htmlspecialchars_decode(html_entity_decode(trim($item_row->contents)))); and I have tried all combinations and without combination of decoding it

Comment: is $item_row->contents serialized ...? because unserialize() takes a single serialized variable and converts it back into a PHP value

Comment: @Sudhir yes it is serialized. I am working on gocart (codeigniter) but I have separate file thats why I wrote my query.On backend of gocart it is unserializing it and working perfect

Comment: unserialize(): Error at offset 1451 of 2467

Answer (score 0):

Your serialized data is malformed. Try this:

```
$serialized = 'a:31:{s:2:"id";s:2:"71";s:3:"sku";s:6:"cp1038";s:4:"name";s:25:"Dual tone stripped pillow";s:4:"slug";s:29:"dual-tone-stripped-pillow-222";s:8:"route_id";s:3:"152";s:11:"description";s:1139:"Address Home, a brand new Luxe Lifestyle boutique, Everything from plus bed and table Linen to cushions, curtain and upholstery fabric in silk, cotton, satin, velvet, jacquard and polyester, embellished with foil printing, contemporary embroidery, crystals, quilting and other types of texturing, including tiny metallic pieces. The current range, which shows traces of Moroccan and French textile influences, but is all about very �now� color combinations - whites and whites; chocolate with teal and copper; black with white and silver; fuchsia, orange depth. coordinate easily with elaborate accessories; German hand-blown glass vases, lamps, lights, serving and dining pieces, glassware, flowers and candles. Even some fab spmdly-legged French chairs, handcrafted from acrylic. Call it my nesting instinct or magpie syndrome, but i just can�t re sist seeking out stuff to enhance my bachelorettepad. Whenever there�s a new home decor store on the horizon, I�m usually one of the early check-outers. Recently, my seeker sense was tingling so much I JUST knew there was something really exciting coming up. And how right I was!";s:7:"excerpt";s:32:"Dual tone stripped pillow 2 exec";s:5:"price";s:7:"1000.00";s:9:"saleprice";s:4:"0.00";s:13:"free_shipping";s:1:"0";s:9:"shippable";s:1:"1";s:7:"taxable";s:1:"1";s:14:"fixed_quantity";s:1:"0";s:6:"weight";s:2:"10";s:11:"track_stock";s:1:"1";s:16:"related_products";s:0:"";s:6:"images";s:460:"{"81503e57d46823464db9e990faa600b0":{"filename":"81503e57d46823464db9e990faa600b0.jpg","alt":"showcase","caption":""},"ba103b97070ede81acab8f593068ece1":{"filename":"ba103b97070ede81acab8f593068ece1.jpg","alt":"","caption":""},"cdd790bd0a17f93af430d663cde823e1":{"filename":"cdd790bd0a17f93af430d663cde823e1.jpg","alt":"","caption":""},"769557dd643978d50d3bd76e5ca3211d":{"filename":"769557dd643978d50d3bd76e5ca3211d.jpg","alt":"","caption":"","primary":true}}";s:9:"seo_title";s:0:"";s:4:"meta";s:0:"";s:7:"enabled";s:1:"1";s:5:"color";s:1:"3";s:4:"size";s:2:"20";s:14:"child_products";s:1:"0";s:15:"mapped_products";s:11:"73,37,36,29";s:10:"hover_name";s:15:"Dual Tone Hover";s:10:"base_price";s:7:"1000.00";s:9:"file_list";a:0:{}s:12:"post_options";s:0:"";s:5:"is_gc";b:0;s:8:"quantity";d:2;s:8:"subtotal";d:2000;}';
print_r(unserialize($serialized));
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:

```
$serialized = preg_replace_callback(
                    '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!', 
                    function($m) { 
                        return 's:'.strlen($m[2]).':"'.$m[2].'";'; 
                    }, 
                $serialized);
```